# How to cancel navigation when user clicks a link (<a> element)?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load some stuff using AJAX when a user clicks a link, but I want the link to actually go somewhere so that the app still works when javascript is disabled. Is there any way to just do something with javascript and cancel navigation when a link is clicked?

What's the best practice? Can that be done, or do I need to replace the link using javascript or what?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you have HTML like this:

```
<a href="no_javascript.html" id="mylink">Do Something</a>
```

You would do something like this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        doSomethingCool();
        return false; // cancel the event
    });
});
```

All you have to do is cancel the click event with Javascript to prevent the default action from happening. So when someone clicks the link with Javascript enabled, `doSomethingCool();` is called and the click event is cancelled (thus the `return false;`) and prevents the browser from going to the page specified. If they have Javascript disabled, however, it would take them to `no_javascript.html` directly.

Comment: +1, but a lot of people will put href="#" in the links they plan on using with javascript.

Comment: okay, I'm an idiot. I thought that was the thing to do but it wasn't working. turns out it was just IE caching the javascript so it wasn't executing my new line with return false.

Comment: @Gromer - The idea is to make it work with or without javascript.

Comment: @Gromer - But, the point of the question that Max asked was if there was a way for the link to work as usual if the user doesn't have javascript enabled. Of course, href='#' would work, but it wouldn't do anything (other than change the URL hash), and hence lead to a poor user experience.

Comment: No as my code is, David. Only if you neglect to return false;

Comment: Try this href: "javascript:void(0)"

Answer (score 48):

None of this worked for me with the Google Chrome browser.

Here's what did work though (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function(event) {
        doSomethingCool();
        event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
    });
});
```

Comment: Returning false does work for IE, but not for Firefox or Chrome; This solution did work for both, Thanks!

Comment: Two additions: 1) One may want to call preventDefault() before doing something cool. 2) Add this in the beginning of the function to support middle mouse button correctly: if(event.which != 1) return;

Comment: `return false;` is not working in my case for chrome, but this solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

why jQuery?

HTML:

```
<a href="no_javascript.html" onclick="return doSmth()">Link</a>
```

...and javascript code:

```
function doSmth(){
  // your code here
  return false
}
```

Comment: Well I am working with jQuery (like the majority of people on this site it seems), even though I didn't specify... but thank you for the post, it may be useful to somebody.

Comment: ok, i see. I think frameworks may be useful to big powerful projects. But for small sites...

Comment: Javascript frameworks are useful on all size sites that care about browser compatibility. Plus, using inline events is a bad practice overall.

Comment: there are no needed frameworks at http://4px.ru/ (:

Using inline event isn't bad for one element. And for many similar elements with similar actions we can set event handlers by script.

Comment: THANKYOU!!! man... people let go of jQuery ... at least if you do not need its more higher functions! Thanks for the post!
--
This also works

onclick = "return false;" 

This is handy if you are using google polymer and using the on-tap="{{func}}" handyness

Comment: +1 for not laming out like an amateur and dumping 70KB of crap that the browser *already* competently handles.

Answer (score 10):

What I would do are :

a. for href attribute, `javascript:void();` will be set

b. for onclick event, will provide a function to handle the click event and that     function will return false.

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myfunction()
   {
      //do something
      return false;
   }
   </script>

   <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="myfunction()">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="ignore-click">Test</a>
```

**with jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(".ignore-click").click(function(){
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

**with JavaScript**

```
<script>
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("ignore-click").length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("ignore-click")[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
</script>
```

You assign class `.ignore-click` to as many elements you like and clicks on those elements will be ignored

Answer (score 3):

for IE at least, just put `this.event.returnValue = false;` at the end of the method.

e.g:

```
function onClickFunction()
 {
  someMethod();
  this.event.returnValue = false;
 }
```

I had a complex method where this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I use `document.location.replace` to navigate, but when I want to cancel the navigation, `return false` (in the same function as `document.location.replace`) doesn't cancel the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way should be this.

```
<a href="javascript:undefined"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```html
<a href="https://ryanhigdon.com" onClick={ event => {
  event.preventDefault()
}}>Take me away</a>
```

In my use case I wanted to perform some actions before navigation.

Answer (score 0):

### CANCEL CLICK ON LINK tag A

> at the moment of holding the click, check the condition data and assign state activity for link

Implemented scrolling of a horizontal slider. Hold down the click and move the content left and right.
There were links inside the content that should remain active when an element is selected, but when you hold the mouse and do move, cancel the event for inner tag a

```
let linkActive;
let cont = document.addEventListener('.cont');


let toggleActiveEvent = (prop, event, revoke) => {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A' || linkActive) {
        (linkActive ? linkActive : event.target).style.pointerEvents = prop;
        linkActive = revoke ? null : event.target;
        return event.preventDefault();
    }
};

cont.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    toggleActiveEvent('none', event);
});
cont.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
cont.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
    toggleActiveEvent('all', event, true);
});
```

МАКЕТ

```
<div class="cont"><a href="/"></a></div>
```

---

[Supported BROWSERs for CSS pointer-events (for HTML)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBIBf.png)

Answer (score -6):

is simple, use rel="nofollow" attribute

```
 <a href="signin.php" rel="nofollow">sign in</a>
```

Comment: rel=nofollow is completely irrelevant. This is for SEO and not for browsers