# How to stop scrolling or moving on next tab if my javascript function returns false

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

```
//HTML Code
<div id="navigation1">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><input type="submit" value="Next" 
       onClick="return checkfhname()" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My Javascript `checkfhname()` is returning `false`, at same time `<li>` tag navigating to next tab form, so I want to stop this navigation if Javascript returns false.

Comment: Why would you ever put an `<input>` inside an `<a>` element?

Comment: I have difficulty understanding your question. Tab navigating, next tab, stop navigation? What do you mean by those?

Comment: i have 5 tabs, each tab having different form fields and at each tabs end i have next,previous button, i want validate fields of tabs1 when i press NEXT button, if tab1 fields are validated successfully then only i have to move tab2 otherwise it show ERROR and keep on tab1.............

Comment: @ThiefMaster So you can *really* make sure that it's something the user can click of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explanation

Hmm, your question is a bit... for the lack of a better word, "iffy". However, I understand what you want to do.

First of all, there is no need to put an input element inside the link when the link also responds to true/false. Second of all, you should NEVER put an input element inside a link.
It's just bad practice.

When you return false via Javascript to a link, the link will not navigate you further, just like the input element wont send you further when you return false from a submit.

This should suffice

```
<a href="#" onClick="return checkfhname()">Next</a>
```

If you'd rather want a button, just change it to a button, add a parameter for url, and use `window.location = url` if you want it to navigate

```
<script>
    function checkNavigate(url){
        //check some conditions, conditions = false/true
        if(typeof url == "undefined" || !conditions) 
            return false;

        window.location = url;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<button onClick="checkNavigate('url')">Next</button>
```

---

## Solution

[Here's a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kZKWY/).

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#link_clicked" onClick='return checkfhName();'>Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function checkfhName(){
    //check your conditions, conditions = false/true
    //for the purposes of this example: conditions = false
    checkConditions = false;
    if(checkConditions){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Additional information; good to know

- **[Here's a *great* article about what you should do instead of `return false;`](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)**
- [Some documentation on form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)
- [Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866583/how-to-cancel-navigation-when-user-clicks-a-link)
- [Here's another question, asking about the reason for return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript)