# How to track the clicks and options chosen using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking

I have the following select form code.

```
<select>
<option value="volvo" label="Volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab" label="Saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel" label="Opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi" label="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: See here: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking link clicks with google analytics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147487/tracking-link-clicks-with-google-analytics)

Comment: The links you have mentioned have shown tutorials using Google tag manager. Is there any way to do it using Analytics.js ? I mean, without using Google Tag Manager.