# Add link to bootstrap modal caller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a block that calls a bootstrap modal to show an article when left-clicked, I need to add a link to it so a page can be opened when right clicked and "Open in new window" chosen.
I'm new to bootstrap and I don't know how to even start searching for it.

The code is as follows:

```
<div data-ajaxurl="showitemajax.php?id=67" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" class="articlebl col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Test Article" src="image.jpg">
            <div class="articlebltitle">Test Article</div>
</div>
```

I want to add a link around the `img` and the inner `div` to enable middle-clicking (opening in a new window)

I tried this:

```
<div data-ajaxurl="showitemajax.php?id=67" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" class="articlebl col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a href="showitem.php?id=67">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Test Article" src="image.jpg">
            <div class="articlebltitle">Test Article</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

but it takes me to the page instead. adding `class='ignore-click'` and using `$(".ignore-click").click(function(){return false;})` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387629/1336271) stops the modal dialog from showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the outer `div` to `a`

```
<a href="showitem.php?id=67" data-ajaxurl="showitemajax.php?id=67" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" class="articlebl col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Test Article" src="image.jpg">
        <div class="articlebltitle">Test Article</div>
</a>
```