# Javascript confirm box, click cancel not working, page still load

Tags: javascript

I have a project use confirm box javascript, if user click cancel and then do nothing but page still load, i search all about confirm box and i can't find what i looking for, please help me with this, here some code

javascript

```
function OnClickNextPage(){
  var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
  if (!result) {
  return false;
   }
 }
```

html

```
<a href="http://localhost" data-ajax="?link1=saved-posts" onclick="return OnClickNextPage();">Test</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to prevent the default action of the click event, something like `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: @Titus I have tried it before but page still load , do you have other way to solve this ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866583/how-to-cancel-navigation-when-user-clicks-a-link-a-element

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  function OnClickNextPage(e){

e.preventDefault();
     var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
      if (!result) {
      return false;
       }
     }
```

Edit --

Sorry My bad, problem is you are calling page load event in href which eventually fire on priority of DOM

```
<a href="http://localhost" data-ajax="?link1=saved-posts" onclick="OnClickNextPage();">Test</a>
```

Try like this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="OnClickNextPage();">Test</a>

function OnClickNextPage(e){

   e.preventDefault();
    var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
      if (!result) {
        return false;
      } else {
         window.location.href = [[Your URL Here]]
      }
 }
```

Comment: As it is, this doesn't answer the question, since in the original code, the event object is not passed. Also if a user clicks OK in the confirm box, the function is not supposed to prevent the default action.

Comment: @user7417866 this answer not work for me, page still load :((

Comment: @TuấnPhạm Try Edited Solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning false you have to prevent the default beahaviour of the event with preventDefault() function. Here is the code

```
<a href="http://localhost" data-ajax="?link1=saved-posts" onclick="OnClickNextPage();">Test</a>
```

```
function OnClickNextPage(event){
  var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
  if (!result) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to "terminate" the click event to the a tag, to do this, you have pass the event object to `OnClickNextPage` function, then call `.preventDefault()` on the event. `return false;` action does not affect to `onclick` event.

HTML

```
<a href="http://localhost" data-ajax="?link1=saved-posts" onclick="OnClickNextPage(event);">Test</a>
```

Javascript

```
function OnClickNextPage(event) {
  var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
  if (!result) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent event when user cancel
  }
  // go to page in a tag's href when user choose 'OK'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
  function OnClickNextPage(e){

          console.log('after prevent')
          var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
          if (!result) {
e.preventDefault();
            return false;
           }
         }
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://localhost" data-ajax="?link1=saved-posts" onclick="return OnClickNextPage(event);">Test</a>
```

Comment: tks but this answer still not working, page still load if click cancel

Comment: you need to check the result and then take action accordingly.